# Jquery Fixed first column html table

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a html table (generated from a php) that has a large number of line and columns. I've already the header fixed.
I would like to have the first column fixed too using this sample code.

live code on fiddle (only header fixed) : `[$(document).ready(function(){$('#_myTable2').scrollableFixedHeaderTable(800,200);});]/[1]`

[1]http://jsfiddle.net/jassyr/8vwSt/3/

If anyone could help.

Comment: what do you mean by "fixed"?

Comment: Refer [this](http://fixed-header-using-jquery.blogspot.in/2009/05/scrollable-table-with-fixed-header-and.html). It might help.

Comment: you need to update scrollableFixedHeaderTable js file in sfht.cloneHeader method where .first to replace with :child(1),:child(2) try this